# Spacing For Image and Text Elements

Tags: html, css, spacing

I am trying to create individual image & text sections.

When the image & text section contains a lot of content, the content will never go under the image. The content always stays within it's content area.

***this is the issue I keep having....the text keeps wrapping under the image, and the spacing is not even between each image & text section.**

Below is sample code I have been tinkering with, but so far I have not been able to get the result I explained above, and in the image example below.

I have tried/added the following CSS to the paragraph tag individually, but still not working as desired.
overflow: hidden;
display: block;

I don't have a URL/page to share since I am creating this page locally.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
&nbsp;

<a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/sample-image-name.jpg"><img 
class="alignleft wp-image-45473 size-medium" src="https://example.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2021/11/sample-image-name.jpg" alt="first-name-last-name" width="200" 
height="200" /></a>
<h3>First Last Name</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
mollit anim id est laborum.

&nbsp;
```

[image]

Comment: The image that you provide does not look anything like the code that you provided. So what is the problem area of the image, if the image has anything to do with the code that was provided.

Comment: Hey there! have you tried using DIVs? take a look a this code: https://codepen.io/blue_ssandro/pen/MWvBoxQ

Comment: @Officer Erik K The only difference is I added an H3 tag and maybe the lorum ipsum content is different. Other than that there really isn't much of a difference. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Do you want the text to wrap under the image or do you want it to stay in its own column? I am not clear as you seem to be saying both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, i can guess that you use wordpress.

So, most likely you could use bootstrap classes to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

I would recommend you, to have a look at [Bootstrap 4 Media lists](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/media-object/#media-list)

As for an example code, with pure css and html, of what are you trying to do check this out:

```css
.block-container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.text-container {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- BLOCK START -->
<div class="block-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/sample-image-name.jpg"><img class="alignleft wp-image-45473 size-medium" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="first-name-last-name" width="200" height="200" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <h3>First Last Name</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
<!-- BLOCK END -->
<!-- BLOCK START -->
<div class="block-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/sample-image-name.jpg"><img class="alignleft wp-image-45473 size-medium" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="first-name-last-name" width="200" height="200" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <h3>First Last Name</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
<!-- BLOCK END -->
<!-- BLOCK START -->
<div class="block-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/sample-image-name.jpg"><img class="alignleft wp-image-45473 size-medium" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="first-name-last-name" width="200" height="200" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <h3>First Last Name</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
<!-- BLOCK END -->
<!-- BLOCK START -->
<div class="block-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/sample-image-name.jpg"><img class="alignleft wp-image-45473 size-medium" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="first-name-last-name" width="200" height="200" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <h3>First Last Name</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
<!-- BLOCK END -->
<!-- BLOCK START -->
<div class="block-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/sample-image-name.jpg"><img class="alignleft wp-image-45473 size-medium" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="first-name-last-name" width="200" height="200" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <h3>First Last Name</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
<!-- BLOCK END -->
```

Comment: Alejo_Blue and Greg Vlachokostas thank you both for helping me out with this question. Both of your answers work very well. Thank you!